# Handlebars.js - variable as arrow key

Tags: handlebars.js

I have JSON. I want to output an array element by a variable key. How can I do it? `key` is a variable.

```
{
  "key": 1,
  "last_request": {
    "items": [
      {
        "town": "London"
      },
      {
        "town": "Paris"
      },
      {
        "town": "Lisbon"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I use `{{last_request.items.[0].town}}`, I have no problem.
But `{{last_request.items.[key].town}}` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars has a [built-in lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) for the purpose of getting a value from an object using a dynamic key. In your case, because the `key` is not the final property lookup, but `town` is, you would need to use `lookup` twice, in a nested fashion. The inner lookup would get the item at `key` and the outer lookup would get the `town`. The result would be:

```
{{lookup (lookup last_request.items key) 'town'}}
```

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`{{lookup (lookup last_request.items key) 'town'}}`);

const data = {
  "key": 1,
  "last_request": {
    "items": [
      {
        "town": "London"
      },
      {
        "town": "Paris"
      },
      {
        "town": "Lisbon"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const output = template(data);

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.8/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```